# Finding the sample space of putting identical balls in identical boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

My apologies for the vague title, I truly  couldn't think  of a better one.
The question itself is quite tame compared to what's usually asked here, but is as follows:

Suppose you have *n* balls and *k* different "boxes" to put them in. Both the boxes and the balls are said to be identical. I have found two ways to compute the number of items in the sample space, *n(S)* , however, they give different answers. They are:

Method one:
Take a singular ball. The ball has *k* different "options" for which ball to go into (As each ball can go into any one of the boxes). Over *n* balls, this amounts to *k* * *k* * *k*... giving $k^n$ as the value for *n(S)*

(While I do see some flaws with this, namely that initially there is no way that there are *k* options as all the boxes are (at least initially) identical, this leads to the official answer in a JEE mains 2015 question, given at the end of the question. So could both methods be wrong ?)

Method two (using combinatorics):
This is more hack-ey, but I can't find any logical errors:

Take the *n* balls, and arrange them in a list first: [*b*,*b*,...*b*]. As to split a set into *k* other sets, you need *k-1* divisions/lines to seperate them, add that many lines in the list. These effectively divides the list into *k* pieces which can be thought each of as a box.

Now (for example) the list looks like [*b*,*b*,*|*,*b*,*b*....*b*], with *n(b)* = n and *n(k)* = k-1

Now, using combinatorics, we get the possible number of configurations possible as $$n(s)=\dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{n!*(k-1)!}$$
Which gives quite different values from $k^n!$

UPDATE:
Method 3: (from the official cengage answer key):
I  do not understand this well, thefeore copying it word for word
(This, unlike the previous two answers gives the answer to the entire question, which is

> If 12 identical balls are to be placed in 3 identical boxes, then the probability that one of the boxes contains exactly 3 balls

I can't separate out the creation of the sample space, hence the whole answer:

Since the 3 boxes are identical, the probability of selecting a box in which we are to put 3 balls is 1/3

p = 1/3; q = 1 - 1/3 =2/3

Probability that the selected box should contain exactly 3 balls is the same as probability of exactly 3 succesess in 12 trials ( putting the 12 balls in 3 boxes).

∴  Required probability  = $\binom nk *(\frac 1 3)^3*(\frac 2 3)^9 = (\frac {55} 3)*(\frac 2 3)^{11}$

So which is correct ? What is wrong with the other ones ?
(Note: This question is a step in solving this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdHutb_zp8Q), where they use method one.)

Comment: If by sample space you mean the set of possible ways to put the balls into the boxes then I'd say the natural thing was the set of multisets $\{n_1, \cdots, n_k\}$ with $n_i≥0$ (and integral) and $\sum n_i=n$.

Comment: Your first attempt, $k^n$, counts the number of functions from the set of balls to the set of boxes. That would be  appropriate if the balls were distinguishable (also called *labeled*) and the boxes were too. Your second attempt, ${n+k-1}\choose{n}$, would be appropriate if the balls were identical and the boxes were distinguishable: for example , it counts (OO, O) and (O, OO) separately.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum As mentioned, everything is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of thinking of the problem: How many ways are there of expressing $n$ as the sum of $k$ non-negative integers? The probability question at the end becomes "Of the ways of expressing $12$ as the sum of $3$ non-negative integers, how many include $3$ as one of the integers?"

The latter part of the last question has a straight-forward answer. If $3$ is one of the integers, then the sum of the other two must be $9$. As $9$ is not even, the two integers must be different. Thus there are $5$ choices for the lower integer: $0,1,2,3,4$. The upper integer is completely determined by this choice, so there are five ways of expressing $12$ as the sum of three non-negative integers, one of which is $3$.

To find the solution to the first question, develop a recursion: Define $S(n, k, m)$ to be the number of ways of expressing $n$ as the sum of $k$ integers $\ge m$. But if we have such a sum, we can subtract $m$ from each of the summands to get a sum equal to $n-km$ of non-negative integers. Thus $S(n,k,m) = S(n-km,k,0)$.

Now in a sum of $S(n,k,0)$, the smallest summand can be no greater than $\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor$, since if all the summands were higher than this, the summation would be greater than $n$. For each $0 \le m \le\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor$, the remaining $k-1$ integers must be $\ge m$ and sum to $n-m$. That is,
$$\begin{align}S(n,k,0) &= \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/k \rfloor}S(n-m,k-1,m) 
\\&= \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/k \rfloor}S(n-n-(k-1)m, k-1,0) 
\\&= \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/k \rfloor}S(n-km,k-1,0)\end{align}$$

Having served its purpose, drop the third argument by defining $S(n,k) = S(n,k,0)$, so
$$S(n,k) = \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/k \rfloor}S(n-km, k-1)$$

Note that $$S(n,2) = 1 + \left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor$$ as the lower summand is $\le \left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor$.

This is sufficient for calculating $S(12,3)$:
$$\begin{align}S(12,3) &= S(12,2) + S(9,2) + S(6,2) + S(3,2) + S(0,2)\\
&=7 + 5 + 4 + 2 + 1\\&=19\end{align}$$

Thus I claim that the probability of putting twelve identical balls in three identical bins and having $3$ balls in (at least) one of the bins is $$\frac{S(9,2)}{S(12,3)} = \frac 5{19}$$

What went wrong with their calculation? What they calculated was the probability of picking a bin, and having that bin contain exactly $3$ balls, which while close, is not exactly the same thing.